# How to split a string that includes a list (as a string)

Tags: python, regex, string

For example, I have a string `x = '1,test, 2,3,4,[5,6,7],9'` and I want to split that into `[‘1’,’test’,’2’,’3’,’4’,’[5,6,7]’,’9’]`.

I tried using `split(",")` but that doesn't work because of the `","` inside the list itself.

Comment: What do you want to happen if `x='1,[2'` or `x='1,2,'`? Are those possible?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I'm just curious as to why you want people to stop down-voting? Do you not agree this a low quality question with poor formatting, no MCVE, and no clear input and and output for certain cases? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @ChristianDean, and all your words should be written before downvoting if the OP hadn't reflected

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Interesting point. Thank you. And yes, I usually do do, this. I'll comment, and then wait to see if the OP will address my concerns/critiques. But in defense, can't you just simply remove your down vote once the OP edits their question?

Comment: @ChristianDean, yes, I'm also acting that way(waiting, making desicion)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest please note that trying to [cancel downvotes with upvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311406/2301450) is a poor idea.

Comment: @vaultah, It's not about that. I recognize when the question is "poor", but I encountered some cases when newbie people get frustrated after bomb-downvoting ... and leave SO(up to deleting their profile). Some people just can "get close to heart" (I meant a novice people)

Comment: It is a legit question. I was unable to find a duplicate. Expecting a complete and fully formed perfect question from someone who has never asked or answered a question is expecting too much I think. That is why SO has group editing -- so the more experienced can help out the less experienced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hack [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to do this:

```
>>> import csv
>>> s='1,test, 2,3,4,[5,6,7],9'
>>> next(csv.reader([s.replace('[','"').replace(']','"')]))
['1', 'test', ' 2', '3', '4', '5,6,7', '9']
```

And if you want the braces:

```
>>> ["[{}]".format(e) if "," in e else e for e in next(csv.reader([s.replace('[','"').replace(']','"')]))]
['1', 'test', ' 2', '3', '4', '[5,6,7]', '9']
```

Or, use a [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\[[^\]]+\]|[^,]+', s)
['1', 'test', ' 2', '3', '4', '[5,6,7]', '9']
```

Pattern is explained [here](https://regex101.com/r/JDGfon/1/)

Comment: Alternative to `str.replace`: `s.translate(str.maketrans('[]','""'))`